# Get distinct records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data table giving following results:

```
number  code
1        A
1        B
1        A
2        B
2        A
3        A
4        B
```

How do i find distinct number from table having code as A. The number should only have code A in table and not have B in table.
For the above table: My answer would be 3. As it has only code A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.number 
FROM TableName a
WHERE a.Code = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 
                FROM TableName b 
                WHERE a.number = b.number 
                 AND  b.Code = 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want `A`, one method is aggregation:

```
select t.number
from t
group by t.number
having min(code) = 'A' and max(code) = 'A';
```